# i have if condition in program what that exact value be in that condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a while loop and if conditions in this program and output will be everything is fine. but,my problem is in if condition like 
`if arr[i]<dep[j]` in that condition `arr[i]` means `arr[1]`. but `dep[j]` means, I don't know the index. can anyone explain this code?

here is the code.

```
def bus(arr, dep, n):
    arr.sort()
    dep.sort()
    p = 1
    r = 1
    i = 1
    j = 0
    while i < n and j < n:
        if arr[i] < dep[j]:
            print(arr[i], dep[j])
            print(dep[j])
            p += 1
            print(p)
            i += 1
            if p > r:
                r = p
                print(r, p)
        else:
            p -= 1
            print(p)
            j += 1
    return r


arr = [900, 940, 950, 1100, 1500, 1800]
dep = [910, 1200, 1120, 1130, 1900, 2000]
n = len(arr)
print('min no.of platforms:', bus(arr, dep, n))
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: if arr[i]<dep[j]:
        print(arr[i],dep[j])
        print(dep[j])
        p+=1
        print(p)
        i+=1        in this condition  if arr[i]<dep[j]:  the value 1120 value will be stored  dep[ j ] .why exactly 1120 will be stored  in this condition.

Comment: Why you are staring i from 1 ?

Comment: because i don't want  to start with oth index.that's why i take 1 index.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is little reformatted with the meaningful variable names. Hope this will answer your problem.

```
def bus(arr, dep, total_bus):
    arr.sort()
    dep.sort()

    if total_bus == 0:
        # when there is no bus
        return 0

    if dep[0] > arr[total_bus - 1]:
        # when all bus comes in and after bus leaving 1 by 1
        return n

    platform = 1
    arr_index = 1
    dep_index = 0
    cur_bus = 1
    while arr_index < total_bus and dep_index < total_bus:
        if arr[arr_index] > dep[dep_index]:
            dep_index += 1
            cur_bus -= 1
        else:
            cur_bus += 1
            arr_index += 1
        if cur_bus > platform:
            platform += 1

    return platform


arr = [900, 940, 950, 1100, 1500, 1800]
dep = [910, 1200, 1120, 1130, 1900, 2000]
n = len(arr)
print('min no.of platforms:', bus(arr, dep, n))
```